# Why difference in degree of folding in a cell?

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology, membrane-transport

For a cell to maintain constant volume, input should be equal to output of substances.

[image: Image taken from http://droualb.faculty.mjc.edu/Course%20Materials/Physiology%20101/Chapter%20Notes/Fall%202007/chapter_18%20Fall%202007%20Phy%20101.htm]

My question is, if the basolateral membrane, by less folding can attain the same rate of transport as of the apical surface with microvilli, then why do cells produce more foldings (microvilli)?

Why is there a difference in degree of foldings on each side?

Comment: This is not my area of expertise, but assuming that the concentration gradient is significantly different on each side of the cell, there should be different transport rates over a given membrane surface area simply from the different diffusion rates. Throw in varius pumps and transporters, which can differ in localization and numbers and there should be no reason to assume identical transport rates in the membrane. Therefore I would suspect that the increased surface area on one side serves to maximise passive absorption while the other side acts as an active transporter expending energy.